# Mule TCP Polling Listener with Persistent Socket?

Tags: tcp, mule

I am trying to configure Mule to connect to an external TCP server and then receive streaming messages (XML documents) over the established connection.  I've created a custom protocol which plucks the XML from the InputStream, however, the TCP Polling Connector seems to be closing the socket and then re-opening the socket as my TCP server keeps notifying me of new connections.  Below is my Mule Flow, can anyone advise on how to get Mule to establish a TCP connection and keep the connection open, polling for message after message from the open connection?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"   xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:amqp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp" xmlns:tcp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp/current/mule-tcp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp/current/mule-amqp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
    <tcp:polling-connector name="TCP_Polling" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" reuseAddress="true" keepAlive="true" clientSoTimeout="10000" keepSendSocketOpen="true" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="TCP Polling">
        <reconnect/>
        <tcp:custom-protocol class="esb.mule.XMLTCPProtocol"/>
    </tcp:polling-connector>
    <amqp:connector name="local_rabbitmq" validateConnections="true" doc:name="AMQP Connector"     >
        <reconnect frequency="5000" count="3"/>
    </amqp:connector>
    <amqp:endpoint exchangeName="xml.exchange" exchangeType="topic" exchangeDurable="true" name="xml_topic_endpoint" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="AMQP"/>
    <flow name="XML_TCP_ReaderFlow" doc:name="XML_TCP_ReaderFlow">
        <tcp:inbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="28001" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="TCP" connector-ref="TCP_Polling"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Before Processing"/>
        <scripting:transformer doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[p = message.payload;
xml = p.substring (p.indexOf("<?xml"));
rkey = "com.lmco.";
matcher = (p =~ /<trackNumber>(.*)<\/trackNumber>/);
if (matcher.getCount () > 0) {
  rkey += "track.number."+ matcher[0][1];
}else{
  matcher = (p =~ /<arcid><identifier>([A-Za-z0-9]*)<\/identifier>/);
  if (matcher.getCount () > 0) {
    rkey += "flight.arcid."+ matcher[0][1];
  }else{
    rkey += "unknown";
  }
}
message.setOutboundProperty ("routing-key", rkey);
message.payload = xml;]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:transformer>
        <echo-component doc:name="After Processing"/>
        <amqp:outbound-endpoint     responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="local_rabbitmq" doc:name="AMQP" ref="xml_topic_endpoint"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

UPDATE
As requested I enabled logging on org.mule.transport.tcp and the following output is the result (removed some output for brevity):

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Initializing app 'darts_tcp_reader'                      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:34,091 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising RegistryBroker
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:34,226 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleApplicationContext: Refreshing org.mule.config.spring.MuleApplicationContext@2d7aece8: startup date [Tue Jan 21 17:38:34 GMT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:34,311 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/Applications/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201401021511/mule/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar!/mule-spring-config.xml]
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:34,597 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/Applications/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201401021511/mule/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:34,919 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean '_muleConfiguration': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.MuleConfigurationConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/Applications/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201401021511/mule/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.MuleConfigurationConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/Applications/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201401021511/mule/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]]
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:34,919 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean '_muleConfiguration': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.MuleConfigurationConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/Applications/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201401021511/mule/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.MuleConfigurationConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/Applications/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201401021511/mule/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]]
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:34,921 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean '_muleNotificationManager': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.ServerNotificationManagerConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/Applications/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201401021511/mule/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.ServerNotificationManagerConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/Applications/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201401021511/mule/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]]
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:34,921 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean '_muleNotificationManager': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.ServerNotificationManagerConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/Applications/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201401021511/mule/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.ServerNotificationManagerConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/Applications/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201401021511/mule/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]]
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:34,929 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean '_muleSystemModel': replacing [Root bean: class [org.mule.model.seda.SedaModel]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose] with [Root bean: class [org.mule.model.seda.SedaModel]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose]
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:34,936 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/Users/jpbarto/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/darts_tcp_reader/DARTS TCP Reader.xml]
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:35,123 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'TCP_Polling': replacing [Root bean: class [org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose] with [Root bean: class [org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose]
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:35,158 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'local_rabbitmq': replacing [Root bean: class [org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpConnector]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose] with [Root bean: class [org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpConnector]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose]
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:35,166 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'dart_topic_endpoint': replacing [Root bean: class [org.mule.endpoint.EndpointURIEndpointBuilder]; scope=prototype; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.mule.endpoint.EndpointURIEndpointBuilder]; scope=prototype; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:35,171 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'DARTS_TCP_ReaderFlow': replacing [Root bean: class [org.mule.construct.Flow]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose] with [Root bean: class [org.mule.construct.Flow]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose]
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:35,357 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1cecd92c: defining beans [_muleCustomEditorConfigurer,_muleObjectNameProcessor,_mulePropertyPlaceholderProcessor,_muleSimpleRegistryBootstrap,_muleNotificationManager,_muleAnnotationsProcessor,_muleTransformerAnnotationProcessor,_muleConfiguration,._muleNotificationManager:notification.1,._muleNotificationManager:notification.2,._muleNotificationManager:notification.3,._muleNotificationManager:notification.4,._muleNotificationManager:notification.5,._muleNotificationManager:notification.6,._muleNotificationManager:notification.7,._muleNotificationManager:notification.8,._muleNotificationManager:notification.9,._muleNotificationManager:notification.10,_muleSystemModel,_defaultInMemoryQueueStore,_defaultPersistentQueueStore,_defaultInMemoryObjectStore,_defaultPersistentObjectStore,_defaultUserObjectStore,_defaultTransientUserObjectStore,_muleQueueManager,_muleObjectStoreManager,_muleSecurityManager,_muleMessageProcessingManager,_muleProperties,_muleEndpointFactory,_muleStreamCloserService,_defaultThreadingProfile,_converterResolver,_defaultMessageDispatcherThreadingProfile,_defaultMessageRequesterThreadingProfile,_defaultMessageReceiverThreadingProfile,_defaultServiceThreadingProfile,_defaultRetryPolicyTemplate,_muleExpressionLanguage,_muleLockFactory,_muleLockProvider,_muleProcessingTimeWatcher,TCP_Polling,.TCP_Polling:reconnect.11,local_rabbitmq,.local_rabbitmq:reconnect.12,dart_topic_endpoint,DARTS_TCP_ReaderFlow,.DARTS_TCP_ReaderFlow:inbound-endpoint.13,.DARTS_TCP_ReaderFlow:echo-component.14,.DARTS_TCP_ReaderFlow:transformer.15,.DARTS_TCP_ReaderFlow:transformer.15:script.16,.DARTS_TCP_ReaderFlow:echo-component.17,ref:dart_topic_endpoint.18]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:35,931 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising model: _muleSystemModel
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:35,991 [main] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: Set Connector name to: TCP_Polling
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:35,991 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising connector: TCP_Polling
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:36,002 [main] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: Loading DispatcherFactory for connector: TCP_Polling (org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector)
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:36,003 [main] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: Loading RequesterFactory for connector: TCP_Polling (org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector)
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,033 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising connector: local_rabbitmq
WARN  2014-01-21 17:38:36,086 [main] org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor: Invalid JavaBean property 'port' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.mule.endpoint.URIBuilder.setPort(java.lang.String)]: [public void org.mule.endpoint.URIBuilder.setPort(int)]
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,441 [main] org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Initialising flow: DARTS_TCP_ReaderFlow
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,441 [main] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: Initialising exception listener: org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy@171fcdde
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,446 [main] org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager: Initialising component: component.2011100149
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,447 [main] org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager: Initialising component: component.532231462
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,457 [main] org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder: Configured Mule using "org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder" with configuration resource(s): "[ConfigResource{resourceName='/Users/jpbarto/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/darts_tcp_reader/DARTS TCP Reader.xml'}]"
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,457 [main] org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder: Configured Mule using "org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder" with configuration resource(s): "[ConfigResource{resourceName='/Users/jpbarto/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/darts_tcp_reader/DARTS TCP Reader.xml'}]"
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,457 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: Monitoring for hot-deployment: /Users/jpbarto/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/darts_tcp_reader/DARTS TCP Reader.xml
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,458 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Starting app 'darts_tcp_reader'                          +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,463 [main] org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueManager: Starting ResourceManager
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,470 [main] org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueManager: Started ResourceManager
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:36,472 [main] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: Connecting: PollingTcpConnector
{
  name=TCP_Polling
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=7aa36771
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=false
  supportedProtocols=[tcp]
  serviceOverrides=
    message.receiver=org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpMessageReceiver
}

INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,473 [main] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: Connected: PollingTcpConnector
{
  name=TCP_Polling
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=7aa36771
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[tcp]
  serviceOverrides=
    message.receiver=org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpMessageReceiver
}

INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,473 [main] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: Starting: PollingTcpConnector
{
  name=TCP_Polling
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=7aa36771
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[tcp]
  serviceOverrides=
    message.receiver=org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpMessageReceiver
}

INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,473 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting connector: TCP_Polling
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,562 [main] org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpConnector: Connected: AmqpConnector
{
  name=local_rabbitmq
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=43886a34
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[amqp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,562 [main] org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpConnector: Starting: AmqpConnector
{
  name=local_rabbitmq
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=43886a34
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[amqp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,562 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting connector: local_rabbitmq
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,567 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting model: _muleSystemModel
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,568 [main] org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Starting flow: DARTS_TCP_ReaderFlow
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,569 [main] org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager: Starting component: component.2011100149
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,573 [main] org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager: Starting component: component.532231462
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,575 [main] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: Registering listener: DARTS_TCP_ReaderFlow on endpointUri: tcp://127.0.0.1:28001
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,582 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'null'. Object is: PollingTcpMessageReceiver
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:36,583 [main] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpMessageReceiver: Connecting: PollingTcpMessageReceiver{this=4e01c1f2, receiverKey=tcp://127.0.0.1:28001, endpoint=tcp://127.0.0.1:28001}
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,583 [main] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpMessageReceiver: Connecting clusterizable message receiver
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:36,583 [main] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpMessageReceiver: Connected: tcp://127.0.0.1:28001
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,583 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'null'. Object is: PollingTcpMessageReceiver
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,583 [main] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpMessageReceiver: Starting clusterizable message receiver
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:36,585 [main] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpMessageReceiver: PollingTcpMessageReceiver@4e01c1f2 scheduled ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@54828e7 with 1000 MILLISECONDS polling frequency
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,594 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: Reload interval: 3000
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,595 [main] org.mule.module.management.agent.WrapperManagerAgent: This JVM hasn't been launched by the wrapper, the agent will not run.
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,621 [main] org.mule.module.management.agent.JmxAgent: Attempting to register service with name: Mule.darts_tcp_reader:type=Endpoint,service="DARTS_TCP_ReaderFlow",connector=TCP_Polling,name="endpoint.tcp.127.0.0.1.28001"
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,621 [main] org.mule.module.management.agent.JmxAgent: Registered Endpoint Service with name: Mule.darts_tcp_reader:type=Endpoint,service="DARTS_TCP_ReaderFlow",connector=TCP_Polling,name="endpoint.tcp.127.0.0.1.28001"
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,622 [main] org.mule.module.management.agent.JmxAgent: Registered Connector Service with name Mule.darts_tcp_reader:type=Connector,name="TCP.Polling"
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,622 [main] org.mule.module.management.agent.JmxAgent: Registered Connector Service with name Mule.darts_tcp_reader:type=Connector,name="local.rabbitmq"
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,628 [main] org.mule.DefaultMuleContext: 
**********************************************************************
* Application: darts_tcp_reader                                      *
* OS encoding: US-ASCII, Mule encoding: UTF-8                        *
*                                                                    *
* Agents Running:                                                    *
*   Clustering Agent                                                 *
*   JMX Agent                                                        *
**********************************************************************
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:36,629 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started app 'darts_tcp_reader'                           +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:37,588 [[darts_tcp_reader].TCP_Polling.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: borrowing socket for /127.0.0.1:28001/2130734434
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:37,592 [[darts_tcp_reader].TCP_Polling.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: borrowed socket, open; debt 1
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:37,595 [[darts_tcp_reader].TCP_Polling.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: returning socket for 2130734434
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:37,595 [[darts_tcp_reader].TCP_Polling.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: returned socket; debt 0
INFO  2014-01-21 17:38:37,653 [[darts_tcp_reader].TCP_Polling.receiver.01] org.mule.component.simple.LogComponent: 
********************************************************************************
* Message received in service: DARTS_TCP_ReaderFlow. Content is: 'I am         *
* transmission 0'                                                              *
********************************************************************************
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:37,851 [[darts_tcp_reader].TCP_Polling.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: returning socket for 2130734434
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:37,851 [[darts_tcp_reader].TCP_Polling.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: returned socket; debt -1
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:38,588 [[darts_tcp_reader].TCP_Polling.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: borrowing socket for /127.0.0.1:28001/2130734434
DEBUG 2014-01-21 17:38:38,588 [[darts_tcp_reader].TCP_Polling.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpConnector: same as 2130734434? true
ERROR 2014-01-21 17:38:38,591 [[darts_tcp_reader].TCP_Polling.receiver.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at org.mule.transport.tcp.TcpSocketFactory.createSocket(TcpSocketFactory.java:22)
    at org.mule.transport.tcp.AbstractTcpSocketFactory.makeObject(AbstractTcpSocketFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1179)
    at org.mule.transport.tcp.TcpConnector.getSocket(TcpConnector.java:201)
    at org.mule.transport.tcp.PollingTcpMessageReceiver.poll(PollingTcpMessageReceiver.java:70)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.performPoll(AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.java:219)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.poll(PollingReceiverWorker.java:84)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.run(PollingReceiverWorker.java:53)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: To look at the log output it seems that the Socket Pool IS in fact creating the socket every time, why might this be?  And what is the 'debt' value I see PollingTcpConnector mentioning, falling into negative values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really surprised that the socket doesn't stay open: after reading the source code of 3.4.0, it's clear that if `keepSendSocketOpen=true` on the connector, the socket will be returned to a pool and kept open at passivation (see: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.4.0/transports/tcp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/tcp/TcpConnector.java#L211 and  https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.4.0/transports/tcp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/tcp/AbstractTcpSocketFactory.java#L68)

Could you set the `org.mule.transport.tcp` logger to `DEBUG` and trace what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after writing my own protocol (to strip the leading 2 bytes from each message in the stream, the second of which was the message length) and following each step through the code using MuleStudio debug I noticed that the socket was being 'released' to the pool twice and upon the second time the pool was determining the socket was idle and closing said socket.  This of course should not have been happening.  The reason the socket was being 'released' twice was because the MessageDispatcher determined that the socket was not streaming, the next question became 'how to set the socket to streaming'.  As it turns out, in my custom protocol, when the 'read' method is passed an InputStream, I needed to cast the InputStream to a TcpInputStream and then call it's 'setStreaming' method with a boolean argument of 'true'.  This all seems incredibly messy as my protocol, not having created the InputStream should *not* in general practice be modifying the InputStream.  I would have expected that there be an XML flag somewhere on the Connector to determine streaming vs not streaming, OR set some value on the protocol itself that identifies it as a streaming protocol.  I would presume I've done something wrong and that the 'read' method, while it works, is NOT the proper place to be meddling with streaming / not-streaming, however in looking at the source code for Mule's Streaming protocol, this is how it is done - SO I can only presume that this is intentional, and will ask that it please be done in a more clean, appropriate or at least obvious way in future versions.